# Python different results for manual and cross_val_score prediction

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, scikit-learn, cross-validation, mse

I have one question, I'm trying to implement `KFold` and  `cross_val_score`.
My goal is to calculate `mean_squared_error`and for this purpose I used the following code:

```
from sklearn import linear_model
import numpy as np
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error
from sklearn.model_selection import KFold, cross_val_score

x = np.random.random((10000,20))
y = np.random.random((10000,1))

x_train = x[7000:]
y_train = y[7000:]

x_test = x[:7000]
y_test = y[:7000]

Model = linear_model.LinearRegression()
Model.fit(x_train,y_train)

y_predicted  = Model.predict(x_test)

MSE = mean_squared_error(y_test,y_predicted)
print(MSE)

kfold = KFold(n_splits = 100, random_state = None, shuffle = False)

results = cross_val_score(Model,x,y,cv=kfold, scoring='neg_mean_squared_error')
print(results.mean())
```

I think it's all right here, I got the following results:

Results: `0.0828856459279` and -`0.083069435946`

But when I try to do this on some other example (datas from Kaggle House Prices), it does not work properly, at least I think so..

```
train = pd.read_csv('train.csv')

Insert missing values...
...

train = pd.get_dummies(train)
y = train['SalePrice']
train = train.drop(['SalePrice'], axis = 1)

x_train = train[:1000].values.reshape(-1,339)
y_train = y[:1000].values.reshape(-1,1)
y_train_normal = np.log(y_train)

x_test = train[1000:].values.reshape(-1,339)
y_test = y[1000:].values.reshape(-1,1)

Model = linear_model.LinearRegression()
Model.fit(x_train,y_train_normal)

y_predicted = Model.predict(x_test)
y_predicted_transform = np.exp(y_predicted)

MSE = mean_squared_error(y_test, y_predicted_transform)
print(MSE)

kfold = KFold(n_splits = 10, random_state = None, shuffle = False)

results = cross_val_score(Model,train,y, cv = kfold, scoring = "neg_mean_squared_error")
print(results.mean())
```

Here I get the following results: `0.912874946869` and `-6.16986926564e+16`

Apparently, the `mean_squared_error` calculated 'manually' is not the same as the `mean_squared_error` calculated by the help of `KFold`.

I'm interested in where I made a mistake?

Comment: Please don't do ``import ...``, write the packages explicitly. It's only a few lines of code more and help a log whoever might reply

Comment: I corrected that

Answer (score 0):

The discrepancy is because, in contrast to your first approach (training/test set), in your CV approach you use the *unnormalized* `y` data for fitting the regression, hence your huge MSE. To get comparable results, you should do the following:

```
y_normal = np.log(y)
y_test_normal = np.log(y_test)

MSE = mean_squared_error(y_test_normal, y_predicted) # NOT y_predicted_transform
results = cross_val_score(Model, train, y_normal, cv = kfold, scoring = "neg_mean_squared_error")
```

Comment: I tried it, but it still does not have the same results.. 
`926.857139601` and `-7.68871709526e+13`
Thanks anyway.

Comment: @DejanSamardžija difficult to say exactly, since you don't show even a sample of your data; it may be the case that you need to perform some of the `reshape` operations in the CV case, too. In any case, ensure that the *format* of the data is the same in both cases